# Access Control System : IP configuration

Tags: networking, ip

I am installing for a friend an access control system (see below). Documentation is scarce to say the least. My questions: the controller has its own factory default IP address, which puzzles me a bit: isn't it the router job to assign an IP address? Or does the access controller have its own network? Right now, despite the controller being connected to the router, I can't reach it. [image: wiring_diag]

Comment: A device has to be setup to be assigned an IP address through DHCP

Comment: So the trick is to assign a static address in the router dhcp server and then change the address in the access controller, right?

Comment: The device has to support DHCP before it will automatically be assigned an IP address,  that might or might not be enabled by default, but you can always just assign it an IP address within the proper subnet.

Comment: @Ramhound what I do not understand really is why the device comes with its own hardcoded IP address? Does it create its own network or something?

Comment: I cannot even ping the thing at the default IP address...

Comment: Problem solved, the router IP range was excluding the device fixed IP.